# Minimum requirement to boot Ubuntu from GPT partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios, gpt

My third disk was partitioned as GPT format, and was originally intended only to be used as a storage device, but now I need to boot from it as well. I did put a 200M `ext2` boot partition as the first GPT partition.

The machine is an old one which I believe doesn't have UEFI booting but BIOS instead, and I had always been booting in BIOS mode. There is no Windows or multi-boot required, as I only need to boot Linux (Ubuntu) from the GPT disk.

I've consulted the [Wikipedia entry on the BIOS Boot Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition), and seems that with it, an EFI/UEFI systems is not necessary. However, it is not clear how to make use of the BIOS Boot Partition.

So my questions are,

- Since I've already had a 200M `ext2` boot partition, how can I change that to be BIOS Boot Partition using `gdisk`?
- I.e., how can I prepare my 200M boot partition to be BIOS Boot Partition? Apart from changing the partition type code to `EF02`, what else should I do? How to setup the GPT scheme of  `21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649`? what content should be placed in the BIOS Boot Partition?
- The BIOS Boot Partition is meant to store "*the second stage of the boot loader program (the first being the code that is within the Master Boot Record (MBR)).*", then how I'd boot my Ubuntu partition?

In BIOS mode, the MBR is used to transfer booting to the active partition. With LILO MBR, the active partition can even be in the extended partition. How does the BIOS Boot Partition work then? They don't have MBR, right? If I set the GPT disk to be the first boot disk in my BIOS, what will happen next, until my Linux (Ubuntu) is booted?

Thanks